# Trouble using xstring to edit input parameter strings

Tags: xstring

I am trying to use `\StrDel` to modify a parameter to use within a command. For example, say my `.tex` file contains:

```
\command{Word Anotherword}
```

and the `.sty` file I reference contains:

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{

\some{#1}

\thing{\StrDel{#1}{ }}

}
```

I want it so when the command is called, the commands it contains are called as follows:

```
\some{Word Anotherword}

\thing{WordAnotherword}
```

So, in the second command `\StrDel` is used to delete the spaces in the parameter. But this keeps generating an the following error:

```
Use of \@item doesn't match its definition. \new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@d {#3}\f...
```

Have I made a mistake? And if not, is there a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Whether this can work or not depends on what `\thing` is supposed to do. For instance, if it were `\textit` there would be no problem; but if `\thing` is `\label` then such an approach cannot work.

The problem is that `\StrDel{a b c}{ }` is not the string `abc`, but the set of instructions necessary to produce it and `\label` cannot process these instructions. The same would happen with many other commands.

There is a way out:

```
\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
  \some{#1}%
  \StrDel{#1}{ }[\temp]% remove spaces and store the string in \temp
  \expandafter\thing\expandafter{\temp}%
}
```

Depending on `\thing`, the two `\expandafter` commands may not be necessary (for instance `\label` would expand `\temp` anyway), but they don't harm.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. This worked very well. Shamefully, I did not know of \temp until now. I will look it up!

Comment: @jamesthenabignumber `\temp` is as good as any other (usually undefined) command. It's just used for temporary storage.